# Replacement fragments in in pagerView

Tags: android, android-viewpager

`Facing one problem in android that I created a pager View and two fragments lets say fragment A and fragment B are attached...

My question is: There is a button in fragment A after clicking on that button I want to load fragment C which will be the replacement of fragment A in the same pager view how can it be done? But when I try below code content of Fragment C is shown over the fragment A ... can u help me with this please. I searched everywhere but didn't get the proper solution.
here is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Top_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pagerView);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tab_bar);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



    }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Top_Fragment();
                case 1:
                    return new FavoriteFrag();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.Items);
                case 1:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.favoriteItems);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment=new DrikCategaryFrag();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frameContainer,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pagerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want to add fragment C in view pager or just showing the view over fragment A?

Comment: Like  we set listner to button in activity to open a new activity with the help of intenet... I want same thing when button or item of fragment A of pagerview gets clicked the new fragment C must open....

Comment: you can use FrameLayout over view pager , on starting its hide when press on button just show it and replace the fragment c.

Comment: yes i did same but fragment didn't replace ... new fragment displayed over old fragment ..content of old fragment is still there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Viewpager with multiple fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

            case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }       
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

        return v;
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment.java**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);
    
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));
    
        return v;
    }
    
    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {
    
        SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);
    
        f.setArguments(b);
    
        return f;
    }
}
```